# Close Childbrowser forward to html

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Using Childbrowser. My case:

- haveing an index.html file and test.html.
- going to test.html
- start Childbrowser from test.html
- I press the "Done"-button on the top left corner
- Childbrowser is closing and returns to the last open page from my app, in this case www/test.hml

I want to redirect/forward Childbrowser to my index.html of phone gap? How can I do it?

js-file:

// Callback when the user chooses the 'Done' button
// called from native

```
ChildBrowser._onClose = function()
{
    window.plugins.childBrowser.onClose();
};
```

Code Snippet from .m file:

```
- (void)closeBrowser
{

    if (self.delegate != nil) {
        [self.delegate onClose];
    }
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentingViewController)]) {
        // Reference UIViewController.h Line:179 for update to iOS 5 difference - @RandyMcMillan
        [[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
        [[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}

- (IBAction)onDoneButtonPress:(id)sender
{ 
    [self closeBrowser];
    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

And the other .m file:

```
- (void)close:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options // args: url
{
    [self.childBrowser closeBrowser];
}

- (void)onClose
{
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.plugins.childBrowser.onClose();"];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your onClose handler set document.location to index.html. Should be as simple as that.